# Doxygen: Class "A" Member functions defined in separate .cpp files are not seen in the call graph of a calling function in Class "B"

Tags: c++, doxygen

Doxygen question:
I have a very large Class "A".
Class "A" member functions are defined in several files, A.cpp, A1.cpp, etc.
Header addenda A1.h etc are #included in A.h.
Class B #includes A.h. B member function Bproc() calls Ainstance.Aproc(), a member function defined in A1.cpp.
Aproc()  does not appear in the Doxygen call graph of Bproc().

C++ compilers on numerous platforms have no problem with this structure, but it appears that Doxygen cannot parse it.

Is there a configuration option I am missing that would enable Doxygen to see this reference?
Is there a simple reconstruction of this code that would allow it to work?

Bodily copying A1.cpp into A.cpp and A1.h into A.h solves the problem.
But this would make an enormous A.cpp file, one which would be difficult to comprehend and difficult to edit.

#including A1.cpp in A.cpp does not help.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using? Your sentence "one which would be difficult to comprehend" looks a bit like that the structure of your project needs some refactoring and real subdivision. Can you give a small example showing the problem you have?

Comment: Version 1.9.8.  Yes, the main class should probably be broken up, but that's a bigger project than I want right now.

Answer (score 0):

If all the functions of the class appear bodily in the main header file, it all works, even if the text of the implementation is scattered over several files.  If the header has #include's that bring in other bits of header, it fails.

Comment: What do you mean by "Turns out that the problem is with #included header extensions.", you should explain this so other users might benefit from it. E.g. did you use some "strange" extensions for the included files and needed to use the setting `EXTENSION_MAPPING` or ...?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).